# Cannot use remote-addr in ngrok for ssh

Tags: ssh, ngrok

I reserved an address on ngrok and then I configure as:

```
tunnels:
  randi:
    addr: 22
    proto: tcp
    subdomain: randi.alben
    remote-addr: 1.tcp.ngrok.io:12345
```

It works but it assigns a different address averytime even though I have a pro subscription and reserved the above address. (12345 is fake of course)
[image]
Also, why do I get a 1. if I have a US region?
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, resolved by upgrading to version 2.3.35